# uicollectionview: setting specific number of items as selected

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, xcode6

The working is simple.
 I have a **collectionview** in iOS.
 I am receiving number of items as to be selected.
 I want to show this as ON .
 Rest should be switched OFF.
 User interaction is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    loyalityCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSUserDefaults * userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userStamps = [userDefault objectForKey:@"stamps"];


    for (int i=0; i<=userStamps.intValue; i++)
    {
        if (indexPath.row < userStamps.integerValue)
        {
            cell.stampImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamphover.png"];
            cell.selected= true;
            cell.userInteractionEnabled= NO;

        }
        else
        {
            cell.stampImage.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp.png"];
            cell.selected = true;
            cell.userInteractionEnabled= NO;

        }
    }        
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in below method but you have to set proper Code.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//stuff
if(indexPath.row %2 ==0) //replace this with your condtion.
    {
        cell.selected = YES;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selected = NO;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```